# c# CookieContainer not pickup up Html / META cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest

I'm losing my absolute mind right now. I've done plenty of HttpWebRequest type projects and normally don't run into issues that a debug session can't handle.

I'm using Fiddler/Chrome Web Tools to sniff the web requests. I'm interacting with a Lotus-Domino server (.nsf extension).

The website has an initial page which I POST the login credentials too. It in turn does a 302 which I follow using AllowAutoRedirect. This page is where it's setting cookies in both Chrome and Fiddler. However, it does not do this using Headers.. it uses meta tags in the body like this:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Set-Cookie"  CONTENT="sh=Y;  path=/; domain=website.com ">
```

These cookies are not picked up by the response and never get added to the CookieContainer. I've tried adding them to the CookieContainer after this redirect with no luck. The following requests all fail and return the initial login page.

```
var cookieJar = new CookieContainer();

var postData = "username=test&password=letmein";
var url = "https://www.example.com/names.nsf?Login";

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "max-age:0";
request.Headers["Origin"] = "https://www.example.com";
request.Headers["Upgrade-Insecure-Requests"] = "1";
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36";
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Headers["DNT"] = "1";
request.Referer = "https://www.example.com/";
request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate, br";
request.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-US,en;q=0.8";


request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 20;
request.Method = "POST";

var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
requestStream.Close();

cookieJar.Add(new Uri("http://www.example.com"), new Cookie("sp", "Y", "/", "www.example.com"));
cookieJar.Add(new Uri("http://www.example.com"), new Cookie("coa", "Y", "/", "www.example.com"));
cookieJar.Add(new Uri("http://www.example.com"), new Cookie("co", "2", "/", "www.example.com"));
cookieJar.Add(new Uri("http://www.example.com"), new Cookie("so", "Y", "/", "www.example.com"));
cookieJar.Add(new Uri("http://www.example.com"), new Cookie("dt", "Y", "/", "www.example.com"));
cookieJar.Add(new Uri("http://www.example.com"), new Cookie("vf", "Y", "/", "www.example.com"));
cookieJar.Add(new Uri("http://www.example.com"), new Cookie("ar", "0", "/", "www.example.com"));
cookieJar.Add(new Uri("http://www.example.com"), new Cookie("bo", "Y", "/", "www.example.com"));
cookieJar.Add(new Uri("http://www.example.com"), new Cookie("sh", "Y", "/", "www.example.com"));
cookieJar.Add(new Uri("http://www.example.com"), new Cookie("cm", "Y", "/", "www.example.com"));
cookieJar.Add(new Uri("http://www.example.com"), new Cookie("em", "", "/", "www.example.com"));
cookieJar.Add(new Uri("http://www.example.com"), new Cookie("er", "Y", "/", "www.example.com"));
cookieJar.Add(new Uri("http://www.example.com"), new Cookie("browser", "Netscape", "/", "www.example.com"));
cookieJar.Add(new Uri("http://www.example.com"), new Cookie("dl", "Y", "/", "www.example.com"));
cookieJar.Add(new Uri("http://www.example.com"), new Cookie("os", "Win", "/", "www.example.com"));

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var sResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

// this is the redirected URL, so the redirect did happen
Console.WriteLine(response.ResponseUri);

// it does a self-post with a hidden form value
postData = "__Click=0";
url = "https://www.example.com/domreg.nsf/SetCookies?OpenForm&Seq=1";

request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 20;
request.Method = "POST";

request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "max-age:0";
request.Headers["Origin"] = "https://www.example.com";
request.Headers["Upgrade-Insecure-Requests"] = "1";
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36";
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Headers["DNT"] = "1";
request.Referer = "https://www.example.com/";
request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate, br";
request.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-US,en;q=0.8";

buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
requestStream.Close();


response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    // back to the login page
    var sResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: I just noticed that Chrome is listing the cookie with N/A as the domain, path and expires value. Similar to if you notice the google analytic cookies for this site.